# Holomorphic functions on the singular locus unique liftable

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

The example I would like to discuss in this question is introduced by Moret-Bailly in a [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73945/wanted-example-of-a-non-algebraic-singularity?answertab=votes#tab-top) serving an example of a non-algebraic singularity:

> Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open. Choose two holomorphic functions $f$, $g$ which are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. $f(z)=z$, $g(z)=e^z$). For simplicity, assume that $f$, $g$, $0$, $1$ never coincide (pairwise) on $U$. Now define $X\subset U\times\mathbb{C}^2$ (with coordinates $z$, $x$, $y$) as the union of $x=0$, $y=0$, $x=y$, $y=f(z)\,x$, and $y=g(z)\,x$. Thus, if we freeze $z$, we get five lines in the plane, with slopes $\infty$, $0$, $1$, $f(z)$ and $g(z)$. Globally, $X$ is the union of five copies of $U\times\mathbb{C}$ meeting along $Z:=U\times\mathbb{0}$.
>
> Now, the point is that the cross-ratio of four (ordered) lines through the origin in the plane is an intrinsically defined invariant. In particular, independently of the coordinates, we can recover $f$ and $g$ as holomorphic functions on the singular locus $Z$. If $X$ were isomorphic to a complex open subset of an algebraic variety, $f$ and $g$ would have to be algebraically dependent because $\dim Z=1$: contradiction.

Let $f \vert _Z,g \vert _Z$ the restrictions of $f \vert _X,g \vert _X$. Questions:

Q#1: Can $f \vert _X,g \vert _X$ be fully recovered from the restrictions to singular locus $f \vert _Z,g \vert _Z$?

From theory of Riemann surfaces I know that a theorem states that under certain conditions for a closed  $Y  \subset X$ with $\text{codim}(Y,X) >2$, homomorphic functions , which are defined on $X \backslash Y$, can be extended to $X$. problems: $X$ is not a manifold and the codimension condition for $X \backslash Z$ fails also.

We come to the main motivation : I want to understand that $f \vert _X,g \vert _X \in H^0(\mathcal{O}_X^{hol},X)$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{C}$. If we can prove, that Q_1 is true, then it suffice to show that the restrictions $f \vert _Z,g \vert _Z \in H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z^{hol},Z)$ are linearly dependent. Thus:

Q#2: Why are $f \vert _Z,g \vert _Z \in H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z^{hol},Z)$ linearly dependent? We know by construction that $\dim(Z)=1$, but I do not know how this implies that $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z^{hol},Z)=1$. Problem is, since $Z$ is not compact, nor a manifold, the maximum principle isn't applicable.

At this point, I would like to admit that I'm an absolute newbie in complex geometry and possibly I did some mistakes trying to rephrase the example in my own words.

Comment: This question needs a lot of improvement. You've presented someone else's example with a shockingly small amount of context - one link at the bottom of the post is pretty miserable sourcing, considering how much you've copied from the linked post. I think you should at least explain that you're interested in the linked example and attribute it to the original author (who is a user here as well as on MO). As it stands, -1 for a low effort question.

Comment: @KReiser: thank for your feedback. I tried to bring it in a quite nicer shape, but I cannot exclude tha question Q_1 comes from my wrong understand of the formulation "...we can recover $f$ and $g$ as holomorphic functions on the singular locus $Z$..." I have done some remarks on the issue,because I'm only familar with a extension property, when we can recover holomophic functions defined everywher, exept on a codmension $>2$ locus, but in this example we assume that $f,g$ are defined on the codim $>2$ locus $Z$ itself and want to extend them to $X$. this is one of the points I not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with Q2. The statement is not that $f,g$ are linearly dependent in $H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z^{hol},Z)$, but that they would be algebraically dependent. This means that there's some nonzero polynomial $p$ in two variables so that $p(f,g)=0$. This is a generalization of linear dependence, in that any elements which are linearly dependent are also algebraically dependent.

Let's dig in to why $f,g$ as specified must be dependent if $X$ were some complex open subset of an algebraic variety. First, it is clear that any two functions on an integral 1-dimensional scheme must be algebraically dependent: if not, then their images in the fraction field would again be algebraically independent, which would mean that the fraction field is of transcendence degree $2$, contradicting the fact that the scheme is of dimension $1$. This claim generalizes quickly to the non-integral case. Next, if $X$ were isomorphic to a complex open subset of an algebraic variety, this would mean that $f,g$ were the restrictions of some algebraic functions $f',g'$ to $X$ - but then $f'$ and $g'$ satisfy some algebraic dependence relation, which $f$ and $g$ must also satisfy. So if $f,g$ aren't algebraically dependent (per our assumption), then $X$ can't be isomorphic to any complex open subset of an algebraic variety.

Now that that's out of the way, let's return to Q1. You have a pretty significant misunderstanding here: the example is not saying that we're recovering $f|_X$ and $g|_X$ from the data of $f|_Z,g|_Z$. Rather, what's going on is that we're showing that given the data of the five lines at some fixed coordinate $z=z_0$, we can figure out what $f(z_0)$ and $g(z_0)$ are, and this task may be accomplished in a way that does not depend on the coordinates used. The ordered cross-ration of the lines with slope $0,1,\infty,f$ and $0,1,\infty,g$ will be preserved under any change of coordinates and this cross ratio uniquely specifies the line with slope $f$ (resp. slope $g$). This is what the cross-ratio being an intrinsically defined invariant means. So this means that the values of $f,g$ on $Z$ may be deduced only from the geometric information present in $X$ - in particular, the values of $f,g$ we determine on $Z$ would be invariant under isomorphisms: we would get the same values of $f,g$ even if we found an isomorphism of $X$ with some complex open subset of an algebraic variety.

Comment: morally the problem is, when can I reconstruct the global section, if I only know the divisor, yes? can the intuition behind your explanations what is going on my Q#1 also be "visualized" drawing analogy to the situation for divisors: let $X$ be a normal integral Noetherian scheme. every Weil divisor $D$ determines a coherent sheaf $O_X(D)$ on $X$. it's global sections are given by  $${\displaystyle \Gamma (U,{\mathcal {O}}_{X}(D))=\{f\in k(X):f=0{\text{ or }}\operatorname {div} (f)+D\geq 0{\text{ on }}U\}.}$$ In general we cannot

Comment: reconstruct for a point $d \in D$ what is $f(d)$, $f \in \Gamma (U,{\mathcal {O}}_{X}(D))$, if we only have knowledge about $D$ as closed subscheme, because $f(d)$ is not unique or better well defined if we vary $f \in \Gamma (U,{\mathcal {O}}_{X}(D))$, simply because the $ \Gamma (U,{\mathcal {O}}_{X}(D))$ have freedom degrees there, making $f(d)$ *depend* for the choice of $f \in \Gamma (U,{\mathcal {O}}_{X}(D))$. but in our situation the argument on cross-ratio kills this ambiguity, so in our situation we 'can' define $f(d)$ independent

Comment: of $f \in \Gamma (U,{\mathcal {O}}_{X}(D))$. is this the ' right intuition' one should have? thus, change of coordinates means in certain kind to 'vary' $f\in \Gamma (U,{\mathcal {O}}_{X}(D))$. again, I concious about, that the situation in the example and for Weil divisors is highly not the same, I just tried to obtain a kind of analogy for intuition behind the phenomena you explaned.

Comment: I don't think any of that applies here. The main idea of the example here is to set up something about the singularity which can't happen in the algebraic setting and is clearly independent of all the possible ways one could attempt to think about this thing as algebraic. The cross ratio does the job here, so it's used.